# How does trading work between your own cities?

Tags: civilization-4, civ-4-colonization

I've played this game a few times with the tutorials helping me along the way.  How do I get my cities to manage their resources properly?  Some need a given resource and others are full with a given resource.  I know there are import and export values I can set but beyond that it is not entirely clear to me what I should do.

In short, can someone elaborate how the trade system is meant to work amongst your own cities?

Comment: What exactly is your question, could you rephrase?

Comment: This isn't Civ-4 - retagged.

Comment: @ire_and_curses: it's civ4:colonization unless @MadMAxJr means the [original](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sid_Meier%27s_Colonization).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you talking about Goods and Materials?

> As settlements produce goods, wagon trains can carry them to sea ports, where ships can transport them to Europe. [ref](http://www.civfanatics.com/civ4/colonization/goods)

So you could also move them in wagon train in another city, to turn them into finished goods.
The Guns and horses could also be moved using a standard unit.

Comment: Tip: Use <kbd>Shift<kbd> to specify < 100 units when transferring between wagons/cities. See http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/5019/1134

Answer (score 1):

[According to Steve Butts's review on IGN](http://www.ign.com/articles/2008/09/26/sid-meiers-civilization-iv-colonization-review?page=2):

> Our favorite addition, by far, is the automation of trade. The
>   original Colonization let players create discreet trade routes and
>   assign a specific wagon train to run that route, picking up and
>   dropping off goods as directed. While it was a workable system,
>   everything had to be done by hand, with the player setting up each
>   individual pick up and drop off and having dedicated wagons ready for
>   each strand in the network. Needless to say, it was a management
>   headache that involved lots of scratch paper and frequent revisions
>   when goods ran out and the system broke down. The new version lets
>   players assign an import or export tag as well as stock limits to
>   every single good in every single settlement. Then the player just has
>   to set the wagon trains on automatic and they'll start redistributing
>   goods on their own according to the tags and stock limits you've set.
>
> You just tell the game that you want to export cotton where it's
>   produced and move it to your weaving centers and the wagon trains take
>   care of it. Of course, you have to have enough wagon trains to meet
>   your trading needs, and you'll still want a couple under your direct
>   control for one-time transfers, but the new system frees up part of
>   your brain from worrying about the smallest details of your logistic
>   system and lets you focus instead on your actual strategies.