# How can I load to the ship only a part in Colonization?

Tags: civilization-4, civ-4-colonization

In Civiliazion IV: Colonization how can I load to a ship in a settlement only a part of a certain product?

For example only 100 on 147 cotton units available?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hold <kbd>shift</kbd> key down while dragging and dropping the goods. The game will then ask exactly  how many units you want to move. Without <kbd>shift</kbd> game will move either all or 100 units, which ever is smaller, I think.

Comment: I tried shift before but only outside of settlement UI. It works only in there but it is ok, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If I remember right hold down shift and drag&drop the goods should do it.